# Oracle - adding foreign constraint in disabled state?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add a foreign key constraint but initially it should be disabled. I can add it in `create table` sentence or in an `alter table`  sentence, it does not matter. I do not know the reason behind this request (it may be `ORA-02298: cannot validate (BLA.BLA_FK) - parent keys not found` ) but I was asked to do it this way. So what is the correct sentence for this in Oracle database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd want to do something like

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
  ADD CONSTRAINT YOUR_TABLE_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) REFERENCES SOME_OTHER_TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
      DISABLE
      NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I just added this as the first sentence after the create statement and it is practically same as being in a `create table` sentence.